# PHP Using rand to pick between specific numbers

Tags: php

I know that rand(1,10); would generate a random number between 1 and 30.

How would I go about writing code that would pick a random number out of a group of numbers say 1,7,8 and 9?

Is it possible?

I am pretty sure rand is set up to only generate numbers within a range?

Comment: put the numbers in an array and use the random number to generate an index to pick e.g generate a random number 1 - 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that `rand(1,10)` will generate a number between`1 to 10` not `1 to 30`.

[PHP RAND FUNCTION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

From a group of numbers, you can generate like this

```
$numbers = [1,7,8,9];
echo $numbers[rand(0,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom array which you required, shuffle and get first value

```
$temp = [1,7,8,9];
shuffle($temp);
echo $temp[0];
```

[shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) — Shuffle an array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/057106d2befcb8ae278b0e26dc8435403267fce4)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your group of numbers into an array, and then use [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) or [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to select one of them. For example:

```
$nums = array(1, 7, 8, 9);
$key = array_rand($nums);
echo $nums[$key] . PHP_EOL;

shuffle($nums);
echo $nums[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/S1EOM)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this. Create a loop that fills an array with random numbers in the range you're looking for (your group of numbers). After that, you choose a random index in that array, which is a random number in your group of numbers.

```
$min = 0;
$max = 10;
$group_size = 5;
$rand_group = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $group_size; $i++) {
    $rand_group[$i] = rand($min,$max);
}

echo $rand_group[rand($min,$max)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function (or inline code)

```
function SelectElementByRandom ( $list )
{
    return count($list) ? $list[ rand(0,count($list)-1) ] : NULL;
}
```

The `?:` operator ensures an result (NULL), even if the list is empty.

And for your example:

```
$result = SelectElementByRandom(array(1,7,8,9));
```